# Add listeners to cache expiration in Redisson

Tags: java, spring, caching, redis, cache-expiration

I am trying to configure my redis sentinel client to perform my specific jobs on expire event for different keys that I put to the cache.

This jobs should check whether to renew the cache value or to let it expire. Unfortunately, I couldn't find anything like that for redis.

Does redis even support it or there is no way I can do anything on expiration event for values I store in the cache?

My config:

```
 @Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
    public RedissonClient redisson() {
        Config config = new Config();
        SentinelServersConfig sentinelServersConfig = config.useSentinelServers();
        for (String node : redisNodes) {
            sentinelServersConfig.addSentinelAddress(REDIS_PROTOCOL + node);
        }
        sentinelServersConfig.setMasterName(redisMaster);
        return Redisson.create(config);
    }

 @Bean
    public MyCache myCache() {
        return new MyCache(redisTemplate(), cacheTTL);
    }

    private <K, V> RedisTemplate<K, V> redisTemplate() {
        RedisTemplate<K, V> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
        template.setConnectionFactory(redissonConnectionFactory(redisson()));
        GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer valueSerializer = new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer();
        StringRedisSerializer keySerializer = new StringRedisSerializer();
        template.setKeySerializer(keySerializer);
        template.setValueSerializer(valueSerializer);
        template.setHashKeySerializer(keySerializer);
        template.setHashValueSerializer(valueSerializer);
        template.afterPropertiesSet();
        return template;
    }
```

The way I use to put elements to the cache:

```
    public void putElement(String key, T value, Duration duration) {
        String formattedKey = getKey(key);
        redisTemplate.opsForValue().set(formattedKey, value);
        redisTemplate.expire(formattedKey, duration.toMillis(), MILLISECONDS);
    }
```

pom.xml

```
  <dependency>
            <groupId>org.redisson</groupId>
            <artifactId>redisson-spring-data-18</artifactId>
            <version>${redisson-spring-data-version}</version>
        </dependency>
```